# MPI posting meaning

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I have google searched the meaning of posting but I haven't found a concrete answer for that. For instance, in the phrase:

```
once the matching receive is posted
```

does "posted" here mean that the receive operation has been started or that has been successfully completed?

Any comment is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To post a receive operation means to call the corresponding MPI function that initiates the operation. This could be the blocking receive `MPI_Recv` or it could be the initiation of a non-blocking receive via `MPI_Irecv`. Same applies to the send operations. Completion comes after posting an operation and it is a separate thing, although blocking MPI operations combine both.